# Paypal express checkout not working in Magento2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, payment-methods, paypal-express

In my site I am using three types of payment method.

1. Paypal express checkout
2. Payments pro
3. COD

After enabling the payments pro. The Paypal express checkout **Configure** button automatically gets disabled.
Refer screenshot.

[image]

I don't know what is the problem, As because of this issue the paypal transaction is not being done, which occurs in my live magento2.1.7 site.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried changing store view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One of the cause/reason** which mentioned in the documentation is,

You can have two PayPal solutions active at the same time: `Express Checkout`, plus an `All-In-One` solution. If you enable a different solution, the one used previously is automatically deactivated.

Reference: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-express-checkout.html

**I hope this will help.**

Comment: Thanks for the solution, helped me.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem is solved. Please upvote my answer as well. Keep coding :) thanks